# Sending selected lines to another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am working on a project for work. The workbook has two sheets. The first one compares margins for a product. There is a drop down at the last cell of the line. "Yes" if we want to go with that margin and "No" if we do not.
I then need the lines that we pick "Yes" from to be transferred to the second sheet. How do I do that?  Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Using words like "transferred to" is describing a "push system" which needs VBA. If change for frame reference to "transfer from" then excel can thought of as a "pull system" and formulas can work. Using this pull framwork, n your second sheet you would have a bunch of formulas (or a single array formula) that sees if that last line is Yes or No and pull the related data or nothing. I suggest you start reading up on basic `IF()` formula to start.

Answer (score -1):

Try the attachment. Hope this helps you.

How it works:
If you are looking to segregate the (Yes)results for different margins, like margin 1, margin 2 then create sheets for every margin.
Apply the filter function.

Example:

1. =FILTER('Margin Comparison'!B:C,'Margin Comparison'!E:E="Yes")
   This is used in the sheet **Selected Products_Margin 1**
2. =CHOOSECOLS(FILTER('Margin Comparison'!B:F,'Margin Comparison'!F:F="Yes"),1,3)
   This is used for the sheet **Selected Products_Margin 2**

[Filtered Margin Comparion](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Apu-kp1rmkE7mGi4jJ3gcRiB3FXX?e=blZxPi)

Comment: Could you please edit your answer to explain what the code in the attached file does? If it gets deleted for some reason there's no way anyone else can reconstruct what you did right now.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: @DavidPostill , KeyboardCat

Thank you. Edited